# Unable to find Virtual Host Listening on port 80

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2

I keep having an issue where whenever I run certbot that there is an issue. The follwing error:
Unable to find a virtual host listening on port 80 which is currently needed for Certbot to prove to the CA that you control your domain. Please add a virtual host for port 80. This is an Amazon Linux 2023 instance.

The first time I had the problem I create a file in /etc/httpd/conf.d called example.domain
and entered the following : `

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.domain
        Redirect / https://example.domain/
</VirtualHost>
```

I tried again and the same thing happed ( I restarted apache in between). So, I ran `sudo httpd -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS` and got `VirtualHost configuration: *:443                  ec2-IP.compute-1.amazonaws.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:56)`

I thought maybe it had to do with that, but it confused because I did not run into this problem with my other instance. All I had to change on my previous instance was the virtual host as I posted above.

I went to the /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:56 and I tried changing the stand in [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) with my actual domain and unhashed it. I still get the same port 80 problem. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

After looking this over I found I made a really simple mistake. The file I created in /

> etc/httpd/conf.d

was named wrong. I named it example.domain when it should have been

> example.domain.conf

The contents within the file were fine, the issue was the name of it.
I reverted all previous files I made changes to and then restarted apache. Worked like a charm.